# Dominant direction (in SVD sense) of 2D positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, positive-definite

I'm reading over some [C++ code](https://github.com/RIVeR-Lab/apriltags_ros/blob/indigo-devel/apriltags/src/GLine2D.cc#L81) which does a weighted maximum likelihood fit of a 2-D normal distribution. Details aside, the code estimates the positive definite variance matrix:

$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}
C_{xx} & C_{xy} \\
C_{xy} & C_{yy}
\end{bmatrix},\,\, C>0
$$

Now, on [line 81](https://github.com/RIVeR-Lab/apriltags_ros/blob/indigo-devel/apriltags/src/GLine2D.cc#L81) the code calculates the "dominant direction" of $C$ as:

$$
\varphi = \frac{1}{2}\text{atan2}\left(-2C_{xy} , C_{yy}-C_{xx}\right)
$$

Where does this formula come from (the code comments this formula as "find dominant direction via SVD")? Please derive it or point to a resource which derives it.

NB: I understand $\varphi$ to be the angle from the $x$ axis to the dominant output vector, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, buried inside the [original C-code](https://april.eecs.umich.edu/software/apriltag.html). Here's the mathematical derivation.

Suppose we want to find the dominant direction of the general 2D matrix

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{00} & A_{01} \\
A_{10} & A_{11}
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb R^2.
$$

The SVD of a 2D matrix can always be expressed as:

$$
A=USV^T=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\overline\sigma & 0 \\
0 & \underline\sigma
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\varphi) & \sin(\varphi) \\
-\sin(\varphi) & \cos(\varphi)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Since $\overline\sigma\ge\underline\sigma$, our task is basically to find $\varphi$ (then, $\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\varphi) & \sin(\varphi)
\end{bmatrix}^T$ will give the dominant direction). To do so, we expand the SVD (i.e. multiply out the 3 matrices $U$, $S$ and $V^T$) and recognize that

$$
\begin{array}{rclcl}
B_0 & := & A_{00}+A_{11} & = & (\overline\sigma+\underline\sigma)\cos(\varphi-\theta), \\
B_1 & := & A_{00}-A_{11} & = & (\overline\sigma-\underline\sigma)\cos(\varphi+\theta), \\
B_2 & := & A_{01}+A_{10} & = & (\overline\sigma-\underline\sigma)\sin(\varphi+\theta), \\
B_3 & := & A_{01}-A_{10} & = & (\overline\sigma+\underline\sigma)\sin(\varphi-\theta).
\end{array}
$$

Hence we can solve for $\varphi$,

$$
\varphi = \frac{1}{2}\left(\text{atan}\left(\frac{B_3}{B_0}\right)+\text{atan}\left(\frac{B_2}{B_1}\right)\right).
$$

For the particular case of positive definite matrix $C$ in my original post, substituting in the values of $A_{ij}$, $i,j\in\{0,1\}$, gives precisely

$$
\varphi =\frac{1}{2}\text{atan}\left(\frac{2C_{xy}}{C_{xx}-C_{yy}}\right).
$$

Now we can use the $\text{atan2}$ function as we desire to have $\varphi\in[-\pi,\pi]$. This is exactly the expression found in C++!